# Can I use my laptop boot drive in my desktop pc as a storage drive?

Tags: windows, laptop

I am wondering if I am able to use my sata laptop boot drive as a storage drive in my computer. I am afraid of the 2 OS softwares getting confused and messing up my computer. Also, I am unable to wipe the laptop drive before I put it in. Should I be worried?

Comment: Unless you have a bootloader loaded, whichever drive is set to the first drive to read will be the one that boots, regardless if the other has an OS.

Comment: Don't worry, you can put your laptop disk as secondary one on your PC and then format it. Your PC will boot as usual from your primary disk

Answer (score 0):

You **can** technically speaking, you might have to tweak some settings though.

From the question I don't know if this is permanent or temporary while moving times. So i'll answer both situations :)

**Temporarily moving the hard drive**:

If you go into the BIOS on your computer and go to the hard drive/storage section you should look to see if you can put one of the slots into hot swap mode (if you don't see the alternate answer) so that you can plug in the drive while the computer is on.

If you have this setting enable it startup your computer like normal then plug in your drive and it should pop up like a USB stick would. You can use it to do whatever you want. The only thing is if you reboot it might use the OS from the laptop drive if you leave it attached.

**Permanently move the hard drive into the desktop**:

This shouldn't be a problem you might have to change a setting in the BIOS to get this to work and choose the correct drive to boot from.

Attach the laptop hard drive to the computer and go to the BIOS of the desktop and look at the boot device order. This is a list of the available devices that could have an operating system on them, when you switch the computer on it will go down the list and  check if it can boot of whatever is listed there the highest device on the list gets used as a boot drive. Make sure that the laptop drive is lower than the desktop drive with OS so that the desktop still uses its operating system like normal.

Boot and you should find that the laptop drive is there like any other storage device

Hope this helps :)